# Unable to download rstudio addin (plm)

Tags: r, rstudio, panel-data, plm

Basically I would like to download this addin but every time I get the same error message.

```
install.packages("plm") also installing the dependency ‘Rdpack’

  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
       binary source needs_compilation
Rdpack  0.5-1 0.11-0             FALSE
plm     1.6-6  2.0-1             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘Rdpack’, ‘plm’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rdpack_0.11-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 700853 bytes (684 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 684 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plm_2.0-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2343782 bytes (2.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.2 MB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin'
* installing *source* package ‘Rdpack’ ...
** package ‘Rdpack’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringr’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘Rdpack’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rdpack’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rdpack’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin'
ERROR: dependency ‘Rdpack’ is not available for package ‘plm’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/plm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/fz/zyl222y96xb7s_hwz44bn2480000gn/T/Rtmp8krcFR/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: you need to let people know what is your operating system. In my Linux system it installs fine for instance.

Comment: So I'm working with macOS :)

Comment: It worked fine in my linux mint 19 I hope someone with macOS to help you